# Eclispe RCP: Invoke Save all from within my code

Tags: save, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to invoke the save all command of my eclispe rcp from within my code. I spent like an hour without any ideas.. this cant be that hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the saveAllEditors command

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.saveAllEditors(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work onmy first try. The reason for that is that the editor itself wasn't marked as dirty. After setting the dirty flag the postet code worked like a charm! Eclipse doesn't save an editor that isn't marked as dirty!